# Unable to find a character in a string?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am getting the data from different Wikipedia pages. First, this data is stored in a local location (in the form of a python pickle). Here is the code:

```
    k = '9–10000000'

    if '-' in k:
        print('Found')
```

'-' character in the if statement is typed from the keyboard and print statement is not showing anything. But, if I copy '-' from the k value, it is showing the required output(which is printing 'Found'). I don't know what is different between these two '-' characters.

This is the simplest example, I can share here. There are multiple other characters, which are showing the same result?

Any idea, why?????

Comment: That character in the string you have is not the regular dash `-` but rather the unicode `–` (https://unicode-table.com/en/2013/)

Comment: Thanks. It is that dash.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly because the character you typed is the "Hyphen" and the one in your k is an "En dash" (different character codes, but both look the same to the naked eye)

Comment: Thanks. This was definitely the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to run your modified program, you will see that two characters are, contrary to what you think, not the same.

```
k = '9–10000000'  # first dash
print(ord('–'))   # printing first dash
print(ord('-'))   # printing second dash
if '-' in k:      # second dash
    print('Found')
```

where `ord()` gives a numerical representation of a char in UNICODE encoding.

It prints

```
8211   
45
```

8211 stands for EN-DASH

45 stands for HYPHEN-MINUS

Have a look at this if you'd like to know more:
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2d/index.htm